# Intersperse wildcards into string (Google sheets)

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets

I'm trying to do a match on a messy data set and so want to clean it up as much as possible. So I think the best way to do this is to make them lowercase, remove white space & special characters, and intersperse it with wildcards. For example

```
Swift - Recent Graduates
```

becomes

```
*s*w*i*f*t*r*e*c*e*n*t*g*r*a*d*u*a*t*e*s*
```

I think that I can do this with regular expressions but am not sure. Any advice or an easier way to do this on Google Sheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to do this with a single regex replace operation.  But I think we can do it with several of them:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[ -]", "")
=CONCATENATE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(.)", "*$1"), "*")
```

The first formula removes all spaces and hyphens.  The second formula replaces each character with an asterisk followed by that character.  I concatenate an asterisk at the end, to cover that boundary condition.

If you want to lowercase the text as well, that would require another step.

Comment: I just threw a `lower` in there and combined them `=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(lower(A1), "[& .-]", ""), "(.)", "*$1")&"*"`